# detection whether is an e-shop written in Magento

Tags: python, html, magento, url

I'm trying to create a script which would do a simple thing. The input is a list of URLs and output is a list of those eshops which are written in **Magento**.

I've read that there is no way to realize whether is the eshop in **Magento** or something else but I've also read that there is a lot of signs that could tell you that this web page is using **Magento** almost 100% sure.

So I've found this page: [magento detector](http://siteolytics.com/magentodetector/) which can tell you whether is it a Magento or not so I'm trying to use their information.

They say for example this:

> > **Magento** has its user interface files in a directory called `/skin/`. For the frontend (not the admin ui) the files are located in `/skin/frontend`. So if this directory exists in the page source then it is very likely that the store runs on **Magento**.

For example for this eshop: [starkk](http://www.starkk.de/) told the detector that it is a magento and the one of condition it meets is the condition I've mentioned above.

How could I check whether the directory exists? I took a look on: `http://www.starkk.de/skin/frontend/` using browser but the page raises error.

And additional question: Do you know another and better way how to detect **Magento**?

Comment: maybe check the error, you got a forbidden error when you used the browser yes?  `code = requests.head("http://www.starkk.de/skin/frontend/").status_code`

Comment: When the request to a directory gives a forbidden, it's a sign (but not 100%) that the directory exists. By the way, with the link you gave, put it in the browser and have a look at the favicon :-) or direct to http://www.starkk.de/favicon.ico

Comment: You will have to parse source code pages: based on the link you provided, in the js, there are folders called varien (the creator of magento), or mage, and the files have licences mentionning magento. the folder `skin/frontend` exists in the source html.

Comment: @Zimmi Thank you, for starkk it is right but when I check this site powered by Magento: http://www.geschenkhexe.ch I don't see any mention about Mageno.

Comment: @Zimmi But in mentioned geschenkhexe.ch, I can found words Varien and Mage in a source code but I don't know whether is it enough to tell that the page is powered by Magento. Maybe they created another frameworks, didn't they?

Comment: Inside those directories you can read a page, for example: http://www.geschenkhexe.ch/js/varien/js.js : look at the first line Fingerpringting may not always be precise, if the creator wanted to hide the software used, you will have to collect different signs, and then make an educated guess according to those diverses signs, kind of statistics: 90% sure, and so on...

Comment: @Zimmi So you suggest to: 1. get source code of main page 2. (if there is no string 'Magento' in the source of main page) find all hrefs in this source which contains strings 'varien' or 'mage' 3. for each of this hrefs, look at their source code for word 'Magento'? I'm asking to be clear, it seems reasonable.

Comment: I was just throwing in some ideas, brain storming like. I would advise to first analyse clearly which signs could indicate magento usage, sort them according to confidence. As en example, you could try to directly download a file like the /varien/js.js, if it is present with the magento licence and used, it's a fairly good sign. But you will need to determine also other signs, because there are surely shops that combine all js in only one file, removing licences and comments. So the absence of a sign doesn't mean answer is 'not magento'.

Comment: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageVersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum it up:

To determine if a site uses Magento, you typically would first look for signs which can best tell you if Magento is used or not. SOme of those sign will have high confidence, some other low conidence. It could be that you will find sometimes signs with contradictory results. You will need to think about how you handle those cases.

For a beginn, there is an extension for Firefox called [Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com/) (website extremely slow at time of writing), which determines which web applications are used while visiting a site.

Their rules for Magento are in short:

1. HTTP response headers: Set-Cookie with a key named "frontend"
2. Scripts in folder /js/mage
3. Use of folder /skin/frontend
4. In the `DOM`, on the gloabl `window` object, Magento creates a `Mage` Object and a `VarienForm` object. On the links you provided I could find a `Varien` object (not `VarienForm`)

Source
https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json#L3423

I am not good at all with Python but I guess point 1, 2 and 3 would be easy to check (check existence *and* usage in homepage source). If you receieve a `403 Forbidden` for a folder, try a folder that would obviously not exist: if it returns a `404 Not Found`, then surely the `403 Forbidden` is an existing directory. Or determine a file that should always be in this folder and check its existence.

And never consider a result as 100% sure...